# Can simple scripts use GUI file manager to select file?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have an extremely simple script that currently executes a command on a file located in the same folder: `command ./file_in_folder option output`. It would be better if script asks user which file they want.

Can a simple script ask the OS's default GUI file manager to open and pass selected file back to script?

Fake Code:

- User double click executable script
- GUI file manager pops up
- User selects `<FILE>`
- Script executes `command <FILE> option output`

If no, what is recommended way to pass `<FILE>` to script that will execute `command <FILE> option output`?

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want is possible, so I'm not making a full answer; but for a simple script, you're probably better off using a text-based dialog creator, like Zenity. For a quick example, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/244836/open-file-from-terminal-in-specific-application/244857#244857

Comment: Alternately, you can always pass the `name` through STDIN and save it as a variable for later use.

Comment: I second @chaskes, `zenity` is the tool for this. See the GNOME docs on file selection: https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/file-selection.html.en

Comment: @muru Nice link to the docs. I haven't used Zenity for a while and forgot about some of the built-ins, like file-selector. You ought to make an answer.

Comment: Or read a list of files (from `ls` maybe), display the results and ask for a "pick file number 1 through n", using zenity or just the terminal?

Comment: Just tried the `zenity --file-selection`, it's almost identical to the open dialog of gedit & similar programs (on XFCE at least). Use that! If it's not an answer soon I might even post it

Comment: @muru Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Xen2050: If muru doesn't follow orders **;-)** in the next 24 hours, could you do the honours?  If you don't in the next 48 hours, **I will! ;-) :P**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zenity can be used to make a GUI file picker, using the `--file-selection` option. For a single file, this is sufficient:

```
#! /bin/bash

file="$(zenity --title "Pick a file" --file-selection)"
do something with "$file"
```

[image]

Where it gets tricky is handling multiple files. There are only two characters not allowed in filenames: the [ASCII NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) and `/`. `/`, of course, appears in paths. Therefore the only character you can safely pick to separate two filenames is `NUL`.
You can't use NUL since the character has to be passed as a command line parameter.

You have two options:

- Pick one file at a time using repeated selection dialogs.
- Verify that each path returned by `zenity` is an absolute path and the file exists.

Something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS='-'
FILES=($(zenity --file-selection --multiple --separator='-' --title "Pick a file"))
IFS="$OLDIFS"

for file in "${FILES[@]}"
do
    if [[ $file == /* && -f $file ]]
    then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

Of course, even this does not save us from a filename like `/foo/bar-/etc/passwd`. So be careful if your script runs with higher privileges than the user.